# JDK and JRE minimal versions required for GWT (compiling and running)

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

What is **JDK minimal version** is required for **compiling GWT client code** (I think JDK 1.7 for GWT 2.7) ?

What is **JRE minimal version** is required for **running GWT RPC on servlet container** (I think JRE 1.5 for GWT 2.7) ?

The only answer I found is GWT FAQ is [JRE 1.5](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_GettingStarted.html#What_are_the_system_requirements_for_GWT?) but for compiling or running ? It is not clear for me.

In fact, I want to know what the **JDK required for a developer computer** and what the **JRE required for a production server**.

Comment: See [the documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_GettingStarted.html#What_are_the_system_requirements_for_GWT?), this is listed under "What are the system requirements?".

Comment: @Jesper I edit my question at the same time. I have already the GWT FAQ but I want to know what the requirement for a developer computer and what the requirement for a production server.

Comment: @STB Land - it difficult to get the correct information without having to trawl the groups/forums.  Both the FAQ and the JRE Compatibilty statement (under Overview) still say 1.5 compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [build files](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+log/2.7.0/common.ant.xml), GWT 2.7 (and actually since 2.5.0) required Java 6: GWT is compiled with Java 6, producing Java 6-compatible classes, and runs its own tests with Java 6.

Note that GWT 2.8.0, to be released later this spring, will [require Java 7](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/af039fed7e759add13d95385c41111554d433b39).